# select from one mysql table where ids match results from select of another mysql table

Tags: mysql

I know I can accomplish this in PHP but I really need to have it in one single query for easier pagination. I have 2 tables as follows:

S_MATTERS

```
id | name
---------------------
 0 | Client 1
 1 | Client 2
 2 | Client 3
```

S_LINKS

```
mid | uid
---------------------
 2  | 0007
 0  | 0007
```

So I want to

```
select * from s_matters where id = (select mid from s_links where uid = 0007)
```

Obviously that is not the right syntax, I just need to get all the client names from the s_matters table where the uid is 0007 on the other table (id on s_matters = mid on s_links).

Comment: Very nearly the correct syntax if you change `=` to `in`. But Joins are more efficient in MySQL.

Comment: I tried using "in" but it just loaded indefinitely

Comment: Yep. `In` with sub queries is bad in MySQL. It treats them as dependant sub queries and re-evaluates them for each row!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select m.*
    from s_matters m
        inner join s_links l
            on m.id = l.mid
    where l.uid = '0007'
```

Comment: @Martin: I don't think there's enough information given in the question to make that call one way or the other.

Comment: +1 Actually it is very likely that `mid,uid` is a composite key isn't it and the OP is selecting a specific `uid`

Comment: Sorry for a n00b question, but what are the `m.` and `l`? Trying to adapt this for my own purposes.

Comment: @MildFuzz `m` and `l` are aliases for the table names `s_matters` and `s_links`. It's just a shorthand so you can write things like `m.id = l.mid` instead of `s_matters.id = s_links.mid`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "=" to an "in"

```
 select * from s_matters where id in (select mid from s_links where uid = 0007)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM s_matters JOIN s_links ON ( s_matters.id = s_links.mid ) WHERE s_links.uid = '0007'
```

Answer (score 0):

An inner join is what you're looking for

```
select * from s_matters 
  inner join s_links on s_links.mid = s_matters.id 
where s_links.uid = '0007'
```